# I want to change the application state and then reload the activity to reflect the change

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, simplecursoradapter, contextmenu

HI i change the app state and then i want to reload the activity to reflect the change im trying to use notifyDataSetChanged, but its nor working...basically when i select the option "remove", the remove operation works, but it dont refresh the cursor adapter
ContextMenu on ListActivity:

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
    View view = info.targetView;
    long id = info.id;

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.edit){
        Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DetailForm.class);
        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
        return(true);
    }
    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.remove){

        Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DeleteItemList.class);
        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return(true);
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

My initLIst():

```
    private void initList(){
    if(modelo!=null){
        stopManagingCursor(modelo);
        modelo.close();
    }

    modelo =helper.getAll(prefs.getString("sort_order","nome DESC"));
    startManagingCursor(modelo);        

    adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(modelo);       
    setListAdapter(adapter);         

}
```

the DeleteItemList:

```
public class DeleteItemList extends Activity{
RestauranteHelper helper = null;
String restauranteId= null;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    helper= new RestauranteHelper(this);


    restauranteId=getIntent().getStringExtra(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.ID_EXTRA);
    helper.delete(restauranteId);
    finish();
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();

}
}
```

My RestauranteHelper.delete:

```
    public void delete(String id){
    String[] args = {id};

    getWritableDatabase().delete("restaurantes", "_ID =?", args);

}
```

Class restauranteAdapter:

```
class RestaurantAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    RestaurantAdapter(Cursor c) {
      super(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt,
                         Cursor c) {
      RestaurantHolder holder=(RestaurantHolder)row.getTag();

      holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }


    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c,
                         ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
      RestaurantHolder holder=new RestaurantHolder(row);

      row.setTag(holder);

      return(row);
    }
  }
```

i have other topic but all i tryed to do there didnt work...
idk what to do, the remove operations works, butdont refresh the cursor adapter

After i correct the code the onContextItemSelected looks like, and im not using DeleteItemList anymore as u can see:

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int index = info.position;
    View view = info.targetView;
    long id = info.id;

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.edit){
        Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DetailForm.class);
        i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
        return(true);
    }
    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.remove){
        restauranteId=String.valueOf(id);
        //Toast.makeText(this,  String.valueOf(id),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        helper.delete(restauranteId);
        initList();
        return(true);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need a `DeleteItemList` activity. An activity is a single, *focused* thing that the user can do (i.e. a UI screen). Creating an `Activity` for a simple deletion is totally meaningless. You should perform the deletion as is (within the current activity) instead of creating (and finishing) a brand new `Activity` to perform the task.
2. The **quick fix** is to call `reQuery` on your cursor. Prior to API version 11, the way you would refresh your `Cursor`s content was by calling `requery()` on it (for example, after you perform the deletion). Note, however, that this is deprecated in favor of having your `Activity` implement the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` interface. `startManagingCursor()` and `stopManagingCursor()` are deprecated as well.
3. The **correct fix** is to start over and have your `Activity` implement the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` interface. It is almost ridiculous how much simpler your code would be if you did this, as everything you mentioned in your post is done automatically by the `LoaderManager`. The `LoaderManager` registers a `ContentObserver` that will detect when your data is changed. It also automatically performs queries on a background thread, which is preferred as it will ensure that expensive queries don't block the UI thread.

   That being said, this will require a lot of work on your part, so I wouldn't blame you if you just stuck with the quick fix and ignored #3 :). Here's a helpful [**tutorial**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/) if you are interested though.

Comment: its difficult for me understand wverything here, im studying androids app by my self for 3 days, so i wwill check this tutorial and see what happens, thanks

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to stick with it, and leave it be if it is too much to take in right now. I remember when I first started a lot of the stuff was really overwhelming, so you aren't alone. But now I look back on a lot of this stuff and it all connects together. So stick with it! :)

Comment: well thanks for help i decided not use the deleteItemList as u propose, and i modified the code as u can see on my edit =D

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue happens inside of the `onContextItemSelected()` code:

```
else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.remove){
    Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DeleteItemList.class);
    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
    startActivity(i);

    // The following is executed before the DeleteItemList does 
    // its deletion work!

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return(true);
}
```

So instead just start activity for result:

```
else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.remove){
    Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DeleteItemList.class);
    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
    startActivityForResult(i, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE); // check the documentation
    return(true);
}
```

and then you'll be able to catch the return back from DeleteItemList with onActivityResult():

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (YOUR_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        // you are back from DeleteItemList, so refresh the list content
        ((CursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); // or smth like that
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, looking at what `DeleteItemList` does I should say you don't need it, because you could do the same deletion inside of the main activity.

Comment: what u mean with YOUR_REQUEST_CODE, i understand what this changes are doind but idk what should i put in YOUR_REQUEST_CODE..."/

Comment: Please check the documentation for `Activity.startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`.

Comment: well thax for help i decided not use the deleteItemList as u told, and i modified the code as u can see on my  edit
=D

Answer (score 0):

you could just re-query after you delete and then set that cursor with the adapter, there is probably a better way but this way works and its a quick fix